# How to download Excel file from Remote Server -Onedrive and place in Sharepath using SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I have to access Excel files in Remote Server under Onedrive and need to move it into Sharepath using SSIS Package.Could anyone please help me how to achieve this ..Whether FTP or Scriptask can be better option ? If so ,help me to provide the overview and about the permission settings to access the remote server file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: When you say "in Remote Server under Onedrive" that means in a folder on the remote server? If so that is just a folder. OK, it sync with OneDrive but this doesn't matter to you, right?

Comment: When you say "move it into Sharepath" you mean a shared network drive? If so you are just moving a bunch of files from one directory to another. Can you confirm, please?